# shiny ioslides selectInput scrollbar failure

Tags: input, shiny, scrollbar, ioslides

I need to have two consecutive slides use similar selectInputs. When I do this, the scrollbar on the first slide fails. I use "selectize=FALSE" so that the user can deselect options. The scrollbar works fine when it's just one slide.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

````
---
title: "Scrollbar Failure Demo"
author: "KM"
date: "May 20, 2016"
runtime: shiny
output: ioslides_presentation 
---

## Slide1
```{r Slide1, echo=FALSE}
fulllist <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
inputPanel(
    selectInput("Option1", label="Pick Many", multiple=TRUE, selectize=FALSE,
            choices=fulllist, selected=fulllist))
renderPlot({plot(input$Option1)
title(main="Scrollbar Fails on Slide 1")})
```

## Slide2
```{r Slide2, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
    selectInput("Option2", label="Pick Many", multiple=TRUE, selectize=FALSE,
            choices=fulllist, selected=fulllist))
renderPlot({plot(input$Option2)
    title(main="Scrollbar Works on Slide 2")})
```
````

Comment: You example seems to be working fine on my computer (both in RStudio's viewer and Firefox).

Comment: @warmoverflow Interesting. It fails for me on Firefox on Windows 7. What's your OS? What version of R are you running? I ask because I had to downgrade my R version from 3.2.5 to 3.2.4 (revised) in order for my shiny apps to work on shinyapps.io. Thank you.

Comment: That's probably a reason. I am on Windows 7 and R 3.3.0.

Comment: No problems in Chrome!